# AngularJS saving data on app exit then use it on app reloading

Tags: angularjs

My AngularJS app users leave my application in the order page to another website (PayPal) in order to complete their payment then they get routed back again to the application (thank you for ordering view) after completing their order.

Before leaving the order page I must save some data in an object then load it again when the user is routed back to the thank you page. Although routing back to the thank you page from Paypal means re-loading the application, so I was wondering if someone can please help me by suggesting how/ where I can save this object and use it again in the thank you page? Thanks

Comment: How about in sessionStorage?

Answer (score 1):

Try using html `localstorage`

http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

You can store the data and retrive it back using setItem() and getItem()

Comment: I need an AngularJS approach, but thanks for bring this up :) One question though, can data saved in local storage be reloaded even after app exit and reloading?

Comment: Yes, it will be available, but use a key value pair of `setItem(key, value)`

Comment: I don't think so, I've just tested it and by reloading the application (Refresh the page), local storage is gone

Comment: I think this might be a problem with scope being re-initialized, Try to create a service / factory and make it access the server and store the data into local storage, that should work just fine

Comment: They also talk about that here in this page, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/iClmrkE1BA4

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the amount of data we're talking about, you may want to be storing the Object in a cookie. Fortunately, Angular comes with a super [simple API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/%24cookies) for interacting with browser cookies.

LocalStorage is certainly an option, but only if your requirements aren't for IE9 or other non-HTML5 browsers. So if the object is too big, I'd recommend firing the necessary data off to your server and storing it there, then retrieving it in the initialization phase of your app when the user returns.